# Get path+filename of file that was opened with my application

Tags: c#, file, launching

I'm an amateur at c# and I've been unable to locate the answer to this.
Perhaps I am not aware of the correct terms to use.

When a video file is dragged onto my exe application, I would like the application to know that it was launched with a file and be able to know the path and filename of that file. This way, the user does not have to use the file>open menu.

Hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Comment: what did you try? is there some code you wrote?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to research about drag/drop functionality and exe file associations

Comment: Thanks I will try to research more. I'm not after a file association. I think what I want is to be able to pass in a path variable when launching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the command line arguments which were used to launch the application. 
If your application was started by dropping a file on the .exe file, there will be a single command line argument with the path of the file.

```
string[] args = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if(args.Length == 1)
{
    // make sure it is a file and not some other command-line argument
    if(System.IO.File.Exists(args[0])
    {
        string filePath = args[0];
        // open file etc.
    }
}
```

As your question title states, you want the path and the file name. You can get the file name using:

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(filePath); // returns file.ext
```

Comment: or check the `string[] args` parameter to `Main`, which contains the same command-line args.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yeah, that would work too. I just remembered that you can get the cmdline args from anywhere in the code with above method,

Comment: Yup your approach is more general, I just think it's worth mentioning both, so no one comes along and thinks they are different.

Answer (score 2):

When you drag a file into a C# application, it will goes as an command-line argument to that application. Like console applications, you can catch it on the Main method on the Program class.

I'll explain it using Windows Forms application.

Open your Program class on the solution. Your program class should look like this.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

By default, when you create Windows Forms applications, they don't treat command line arguments. You have to make a tiny change on the signature of the Main method, so it can receive arguments:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Now you can handle file name argument passed to the application. By default, Windows will put the file name as the first argument. Just do something like this:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Before Application.Run method, treat the argument passed.
        // I created an overload of the constructor of my Form1, so
        // it can receive the File Name and load the file on some TextBox.

        string fileName = null;

        if (args != null && args.Length > 0)
            fileName = args[0];

        Application.Run(new Form1(fileName));
    }
```

In case you want to know the constructor overload of my Form1, here it is. Hope it helps!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form1(string fileName) : this()
    {
        if (fileName == null)
            return;

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid file name.");
            return;
        }

        textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: All correct except the "you have to" part.  In .NET, System.Environment gives access later (as helb's answer shows).  In a generic Win32 program, the `GetCommandLine` API call does.  There's no need to handle them specifically in Main, the argument is provided there to make it more convenient in case you do.

Comment: Thanks Ismael. This worked for me but I had to make one change because I was getting the text contents of the file, not its path+filename. textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);  changed to  textBox1.Text = fileName;

Answer (score 0):

You need your application's command-line arguments. When you drop a file on your application in Explorer, Explorer opens the application with the file you dropped on it. You can select as many files as you want, drop them on your application and using this line of code, `files` will be an array of those command line arguments.

```
string[] files = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what you were asking. So I edited my answer.

Comment: OK this worked for me also and is the simplest solution. Since it only returns a string variable and not a path, how can I extract only the filename from this?

Comment: It returns all files that you dropped on your application. `files` is an array of string. For example your first file is at `files[0]`. Is it what you are asking for? Or you want to get only filename without path? By the way, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer that was your answer.

Comment: If I load index 1 of that array into a string, it is the fill path+filename. How can I then also extract only the filename into another string?

Comment: Well, if you want to extract filename from a full path, you should code a little. This will work but you should check for errors and stuff: `string filename = files[0].Substring(files[0].LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);`