# Get Path on open ZIP

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zip

I'm trying to make a simple ZIP Unpacker in c# .net 4.5. I've set my program as default program to open *.zip 's with.

I have created a Test.zip on my Desktop and it opens my blank form. How can I get the path where the user opened the zip? (In my case /Desktop).

Until now I've no code at all to show.

EDIT:

For example WinRAR as default program for .Zip and .Rar opens the specific file where the user has double-clicked on. This is what I want to achieve in my program.

Comment: `Until now I've no code at all to show.` update your post when you do, as it is is has no context at all.

Comment: I need to know how to get the path. That's the first thing I need to know.

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004975/get-pathfilename-of-file-that-was-opened-with-my-application

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not to do your research for you.