# C# .NET check if the app is opened by a file via Open With

Tags: c#, .net, file

I'm trying to make a test app that gets the path of the file when opened via **Open With**. So when the user opens a file with the app, get the path and display it with a MessageBox.

In Windows, there's an option to **select a .exe** file **when opening a text document**, video, etc.

**Is it possible in C#** or should I use C/C++? If it is, **how do I do it?**

I'm using .NET Core, but if needed, I will switch to in .NET Framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get path+filename of file that was opened with my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28004975/get-pathfilename-of-file-that-was-opened-with-my-application)

Comment: Yes, I will try. Thank you

Comment: It didn't work in WPF. Should I use .NET Framework and create a console app?

Comment: OK, it works in Windows Forms. Thanks!